# Header include path in files generated by `protoc`

Tags: protocol-buffers

When I call `protoc` like this

```
protoc --cpp_out=. path/to/test.proto
```

the files

- `path/to/test.pb.cc` and
- `path/to/test.pb.h`

are generated which is what I want. But, since the `cc` needs the `h`, the `h` is included like this

```
#include "path/to/test.pb.h"
```

which is *not* what I want. The background is that my build tool (`scons`) calls `protoc` from the project's root and not from the directory which includes the source files. I found no obvious option in the manpage or the help text.

So my next idea was to consider this as "correct" and adjust my build system, but: The two files are siblings in the directory tree, so when one includes the other, no path is needed. Even compiling by hand fails.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Doing find-replace on generated files is most likely easier
than reorganization of your build system (use `sed` command on Linux/unix).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing for my project is as follows:

1. Create a `pb/` directory at the same level as your `include/` and `src/` directories.
2. Put your `.proto` files in there, and create a makefile. Write the following in it:

   ```
   CXX = g++
   CXXFLAGS = -O3

   PROTOBF = $(shell find ./ -name '*.proto')
   SOURCES = $(subst proto,pb.cc,$(PROTOBF))
   OBJECTS = $(subst proto,pb.o,$(PROTOBF))

   default: $(OBJECTS)
       @echo -n

   $(SOURCES): %.pb.cc : %.proto
       protoc --cpp_out=. $<

   $(OBJECTS): %.pb.o : %.pb.cc
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
   ```

   Which will essentially generate and build the protobuffer files when invoked.
3. In your main makefile, simply add the following include path: `-Ipb/`.

   And when including a protocol buffer header, use `#include <whatever.pb.h>`.
4. Add the object files generated in `pb/` to your linking step. Myself I used:

   ```
   PB_OBJS = $(shell find pb/ -name '*.pb.o')
   ```

   And gave that to the linker along with the normal object files in `obj/`.

---

Then, you can probably call the `pb/` makefile from the main makefile if you want to automate it. The important point is that `protoc` be called from the `pb/` directory or the include will be messed up.

Sorry for the ugly makefiles. At least it works, and I hope this helps you...